# Mysqldump rewriting input. Wordpress backup

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am running the most recent version of MariaDB on a CentOS7 machine. I have two databases I need to back up. One for Postfix/Dovecot and Another for Wordpress. I have read a few guides and most just say that I should be good running

```
 sudo mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p somepassword --all_databases > /tmp/backup.sql
```

Produces the output

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
```

However, I suspect wordpress is complicating this process a bit because my CLI input is rewritten as

```
sudo mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p SomeIncorrectPassword find /var/www/somewordpressdir/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;! --all-databases > /tmp/backup.sql
```

I'm not sure why this is happening and I didn't come across anything similar. I am clearly missing something very basic here. What additional options do I need to provide?

I was reading an article that used the 
    --single_transaction
tag and this produced a different output

```
mysqldump: You can't use --single-transaction and --lock-all-tables at the same time.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not "`--all_databases`" with underscore but it's "`--all-databases`" with minus :-)

Comment: Wow I'm blind T_T